# Complex sql query involving timestamp to timestamp periods and joins and sums - is it even possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to create database query, which will select rows from one table, create periods from those rows (using Lag window function), and join the query with rows from different table, where it sums value(s)from one column per row in first table.

Table A:
id,
created_at,
object_id

Table B:
id,
end_time,
value,
object_id

And rows, that query yields should consist of columns something like:

- lag(tablea.created_at) over(tablea.object_id, tablea.created_at),
- tablea.created_at,
- tablea.object_id
- sum(tableb.value) where it sums the tableb.value from matching period

I tried creating query where i put the window function into WHERE clause only to get an error. I also tried puting the period into join on clause but that also raised an error.

It is no problem, if it is not possible. I just want to know if it possible and in that case how it is possible. If it is not possible, then i just will try to come up with alternative aproach.

Edit: link to example sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c7878

Edit2: The SQL i tried was something like:

SELECT lag(a.created_at, a.created_at, a.object_id, sum(b.value) from tablea a left join tableb b on (something) order by a.object_id, a.created_at

But obviously that did not work, because i could not use window function in ON clause. That's where i got stuck

Comment: For this sort of thing, a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with sample data goes a  long way.

Comment: Hi. I created sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c7878

Comment: Can you add the query that you have already tried (but which did not work)? Currently I have a hard time understanding what exactly you are trying to achieve. Or add the desired output based on the SQLFiddle to your question

Comment: Added example of the query that i tried.